# After starting a sentence with a name, do you capitalize the next part of the same sentence?

Tags: sentence, capitalization

For example, in the case of the following sentence, do you capitalize the "Good Morning!" and the next part "It..."?

Mr. Smith, Good Morning! It was a pleasure meeting you the other day.

Please let me know.  Best, James

Answer (score 2):

The simple answer is no; you do not capitalize "good morning." The correct capitalization is this: 
Mr. Smith, good morning! It was a pleasure meeting you the other day.

And indeed, although "good morning" doesn't have a subject and verb, it is still considered a complete sentence -- and so, "Mr. Smith, good morning!" would also be a sentence. That is, some groups of words, such as "Good morning" are considered sentences even though they don't follow the rules.

Comment: The missing words are assumed to exist: *Mr Smith, [I bid you] good morning!* Or *Mr. Smith, [I hope you have a] good morning.*

Comment: I'll stick with the idea that many sentences break the rule of needing a subject and verb: "Yes." is a sentence. "Down with tradition!" is another.

Comment: They don't *break* the rule. The rule is simply implicit. "*Do you agree?*" "*Yes [I agree].*

Answer (score -1):

"Mr. Smith, good morning!" is not a complete sentence.

It does look like something I'd expect to see at the beginning of a letter.  In a letter, the salutation ("Mr. Smith") and the beginning of the first line ("Good morning") would both be capitalized.  Note that the salutation is written on a different line:

> Dear Mr. Smith,
>
> Good morning! It was a pleasure meeting you the other day.

To answer the question in your title, we only capitalize the first word of a sentence any subsequent proper nouns.

<s>John Smith Wished me a good morning</s> -> John Smith wished me a good morning
<s>President Lincoln Delivered the Gettysburg Address</s> -> President Lincoln delivered the Gettysburg Address
<s>McDonald's Is a popular restaurant chain</s> -> McDonald's is a popular restaurant chain.

Also note, there is no reason to capitalize "Morning" in "good morning" (unless you're using "Good Morning" as a title).